# Obtener MAC en Android Studio (Android 12)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, desarrollo

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Android que debe obtener la MAC wifi del dispositivo que abre la aplicación, esto me funciona sin problemas hasta Android 9, pero me están pidiendo que funcione ahora con Android 12.
En esta versión no me devuelve la MAC Adress, en su lugar me da null, (Adjunto método)

```
public static String getMacAddress(String type) {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface nif : all) {
            if (!nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(type)) continue;

            byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
            if (macBytes == null) {
                return "";
            }

            StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b : macBytes) {
                res1.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF)).append(":");
            }

            if (res1.length() > 0) {
                res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
            }
            return res1.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Lectura.LogAlert("Error MAC",ex.toString());
    }
    return "";
}
```

Alguien sabe como aplicar este método para Android 12 o alguna librería que me ayude a lograrlo. Cabe destacar que estoy usando Java en Android Studio.
Gracias

Comment: Hola, des afortunadamente obtener la Mac Address ya no será posible por seguridad para los usuarios, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

**El valor de la MAC Address ya no puede ser obtenido por el SDK, esto por cuestiones de seguridad para brindar una mejor protección de datos a los usuarios.**

Si tratas de obtnerlo usando la clase `NetworkInterface`, podrás obtener la MAC Address sin problema pero su obtención fue completamente removida en Android 10.

Si tratas de obtenerlo usando la clase `WifiManager`,

```
String mac = ((WifiManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)).getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
```

obtendrás en todos los dispositivos el valor:

```
020000000000
```

Revisa:
[**Acceso al identificador de hardware**](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id)